# Why assigning will be error with Address offset on stm32f7?

Tags: gcc, arm, stm32, offset

The problem I encountered was very weird.First I'm sorry for my English and thank you for your patience!
I want to make PB0 and PB1  generate low level to light LED.

First my code is this:

```
RCC->AHB1ENR|=1<<1;  //enble GPIOB clock

GPIOB->MODER&=~(3<<(0*2));   //configure PB0 and PB1 General purpose Output mode
GPIOB->MODER|=1<<(0*2); 
GPIOB->MODER&=~(3<<(1*2));  
GPIOB->MODER|=1<<(1*2); 



GPIOB->OSPEEDR&=~(3<<(0*2));    //very high speed
GPIOB->OSPEEDR|=(3<<(0*2));
GPIOB->OSPEEDR&=~(3<<(1*2));    
GPIOB->OSPEEDR|=(3<<(1*2));



GPIOB->PUPDR&=~(3<<(0*2));  //pull-up
GPIOB->PUPDR|=1<<(0*2); 
GPIOB->PUPDR&=~(3<<(1*2));  
GPIOB->PUPDR|=1<<(1*2);

*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x14) &= ~(1<<0); //PB0 and PB1 is low to light up the LED
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x14) &= ~(1<<1);
```

the result is that led is on.

than I modified a bit：

```
ps:GPIOB baseaddr:0x40020400 
MODER offset addr :0x00 
OSPEEDR offset addr:0x08 
OTYPER offset addr:0x04 
ODR offset addr:0x14

RCC->AHB1ENR|=1<<1;  

*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)&=~(3<<(0*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)|=1<<(0*2);     
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)&=~(3<<(1*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)|=1<<(1*2);     



*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)&=~(3<<(0*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)|=(3<<(0*2));
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)&=~(3<<(1*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)|=(3<<(1*2));


*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x04)&=~(1<<0) ;        
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x04)|=0<<0;        
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x04)&=~(1<<1) ;        
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x04)|=0<<1;    

*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x14) &= ~(1<<0);
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x14) &= ~(1<<1);
```

the LED is off.The two codes are exactly the same.I am confused.so I use JLINK to view registers:

```
(MODER)   0x40020400: 00000280
(OSPEEDR) 0x40020408: 00000000
(OTYPER)  0x40020404: 00000000
(ODR)     0x40020414: 00000280
```

then I try following code:

```
RCC->AHB1ENR|=1<<1;  

*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)&=~(3<<(0*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)|=1<<(0*2);     
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)&=~(3<<(1*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x00)|=1<<(1*2);     



*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)&=~(3<<(0*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)|=(3<<(0*2));
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)&=~(3<<(1*2)); 
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x08)|=(3<<(1*2));


GPIOB->PUPDR&=~(3<<(0*2));  //pull-up
GPIOB->PUPDR|=1<<(0*2); 
GPIOB->PUPDR&=~(3<<(1*2));  
GPIOB->PUPDR|=1<<(1*2);

*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x14) &= ~(1<<0);
*(unsigned int*)(0x40020400+0x14) &= ~(1<<1);
```

the LED is on!!

the registers:

```
    (MODER)   0x40020400: 00000285
    (OSPEEDR) 0x40020408: 000000CF
    (OTYPER)  0x40020404: 00000000
    (ODR)     0x40020414: 00000000
```

I think the function of the three codes is the same，but the registers is different.
my compiler:arm-none-eabi-gcc (from arm.com )

who can tell me why?

Comment: for starters, out of reset the minimum is to set the moder registers and you can leave the rest.

Comment: next examine the disassembly.  try volatile unsigned int instead of int...

Comment: OK ，What you said makes sense

Comment: looks like you need a pull there for some reason?

Comment: your three functions do three different things.

Comment: first and third are the same the one in the middle isnt.

Comment: volatile will make a difference in the long run, it may optimize out some of the writes/reads that you want in there.

Comment: you are right!! i love you!  ^_^.  volatile is effective